# What does it mean to have a template in constructor foo<T>() in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

In the following piece of code what does it mean to have `<T>` after the constructor ?

```
template<class T>
class foo{
    int x;
public:
    foo<T>(){ // ??
        x=0;
    }
};

int main(){
    foo<int>* fo = new foo<int>();
}
```

The code compiles successfully with no errors.

I did some search on methods and functions declaration syntax in c++, but couldn't find what it meant.

So, what does it mean to have constructor like this, and how it's supposed to be used ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A constructor can be declared using the following (C++11, 12.1):

- the injected class name (just `foo`)
- the class-name that names the current specialization of a class template (`foo<T>`)

Further, C++11 14.6.1/3 says that "The injected-class-name of a class template or class template specialization can be used either as a *template-name* or a *type-name* wherever it is in scope."

So either form is fine.

Comment: The template parameter is optional in your example to summarize :)

Comment: Thank you, but just to have everything clear for me. using the second way `foo<T>` has no advantages or more uses than the first way? just two faces for the same coin ?

Comment: @TimDave i didn't see your comment before posting mine